# Notify only when IP changes

Tags: bash, logging, ip, alert

I use this script to log ext IP changes

```
host myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | sed -n -e 's/^\(.*\)\(myip.opendns.com has address \)/\1/p' | sed "s/^/`date` /" » /DataVolume/shares/Public/MyIP.txt
```

How can I create an alert (maybe creating a separate log file or sending a mail) only when IP changes?

Comment: You can use `inotifywait` utility for monitoring change in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

previp=

while :; do
    ip=$(host myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com |
        sed -n '/.* has address \(.*\)/ { s//\1/; p; q; }' )
    if [[ $previp != "$ip" ]]; then
        msg="$(date): IP change from '$previp' to '$ip'"
        echo "$msg" >> logfile
        mail -s "IP change" somebody@somewhere <<< "$msg"
        previp=$ip
    fi  
    sleep 60
done
```

If you want it to run one time only (from crontab, for example):

```
#!/bin/bash

ipfile='/tmp/previous_ip'

ip=$(host myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com |
    sed -n '/.* has address \(.*\)/ { s//\1/; p; q; }' )

if ! [[ -f $ipfile ]]; then
    echo "$ip" > "$ipfile"
fi

read -r previp < "$ipfile"

if [[ $previp != "$ip" ]]; then
    msg="$(date): IP change from '$previp' to '$ip'"
    echo "$msg" >> logfile
    mail -s "IP change" somebody@somewhere <<< "$msg"
    echo "$ip" > "$ipfile"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks; I've two questions: this script always run, is it possile to run this one time only (I'll add it to Cron daily routine); does mail needs some specific code changes to work because of adding my id seems not to send nothing

Comment: @DylanDog I've updated my answer so that it is possible to run the script once. Your `mail` problem is a very different issue. First, you should make sure the `mail` program works from command line. You can search and ask if necessary  in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). Search for something like "sending mail on Linux via command line"

Comment: Works perfectly. There's something I don't get with your code: how can compare prev ip to new ip? I mean I use the script I posted to create a txt file that says as output "Sat Jul 18 17:00:05 CEST 2020 192.168.1.1" that runs every morning; how can I use this with your code? Sorry for question

Comment: @DylanDog Save the script above in a file, make it executable, and add that file to your crontab. The last ip is in the file `/tmp/previous_ip` (you can change this in the script). You can also change the name of `logfile` in the script at your convenience. This script does all things you wanted (saving the last ip and logging).